# How to set LineHeight using AnnotatedString in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm working right now with AnnotedStrings to create this Text with two different text styles:
[image: Image with alabel displaying 1.26 Kilowatts text]

I'm setting up this label using a SpanStyle. How do I setup the line height this way? Because SpanStyle is missing this attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `ParagraphStyle` to define the `lineHeight` and the `lineHeightStyle`.

Something like:

```
buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(style = ParagraphStyle(lineHeight = 60.sp)) {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue, fontSize= 60.sp)) {
            append("Hello")
        }
        append("Compose")
    }
}
```

[image]